# Activity Transitions not working

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am trying to implement Activity Transitions but I am not able to see the effects. Here is the code for my first activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_architecture);
        setUpWindowAnimations();
    }

private void setUpWindowAnimations() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Log.i("ANIM", "Fade called");
            Fade fade = new Fade(2);
            fade.setDuration(3000);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for second activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
        setUpWindowAnimations();
    }

private void setUpWindowAnimations() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Log.i("ANIM", "slide called");
            Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
            slide.setDuration(3000);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
        }
    }
```

Even though I have set Fade out animation, there is no fading, also, Slide works in default way, i.e. the direction is BOTTOM instead of LEFT.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14688359/) is my `values/style.xml` and [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14688366/) is my `v21/styles.xml`.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Why are these transitions not working and how to make them work. I used [paste.ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.paste.com) because the SO editor was not showing xml properly.

Comment: Did you define a style in `styles.xml` with your custom transition?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, I haven't. You can check both my `styles.xml`, I have put a link.

Comment: The paste.ubuntu link you put doesn't work.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky [styles.xml](https://ideone.com/1qpEZp) and [v21/styles.xml](https://ideone.com/Y2T52M)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: yes, it works on lollipop above.

Answer (score 44):

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle();
this.startActivity(intent,bundle);
```

Add these two lines after you setup your intent between two activities,
this will work.

You cannot just start an activity via `startActivity(intent)` method,
you need to specify transitions across activies using bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `setUpWindowAnimations();` before `setContentView`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpWindowAnimations();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_architecture);

    }

private void setUpWindowAnimations() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Log.i("ANIM", "Fade called");
            Fade fade = new Fade(2);
            fade.setDuration(3000);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
        }
    }
```

**Other Solution**

make a `xmlTransition` and put this xml code there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate">
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out"/>
    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom"/>
</transitionSet>
```

This should be your Style for `Api21`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTransitionBackgroundFadeDuration">1000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then put this code in your activity before `setCreateView`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

            TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(this);
            Transition transition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.transition_a);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(transition);
        }
```

this should be in your other activity before `setCreateView`

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Slide slide = new Slide();
            slide.setDuration(1000);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
        }
```

Comment: it is also not working. I changed the slide direction to left and still it is sliding from bottom.

Comment: Why does it need to be before `setCreateView`??

Comment: are you testing it on 21> device?